# Using DataTables Plugin with GET requests to pass requestbody

Tags: javascript, web-services, datatables, jackson, jax-rs

I have a javascript function `fetchGroups()` that builds a paged data table using the datatable plugin. The request being passed in is a GET request. I need to pass a `fetchMemberGroups` object along with the request. I tried sending the request with the request body. But it doesn't seem to work and keeps throwing a `500-Internal Server Error`. I also don't believe I can pass a request body with a GET. I then tried to pass the `fetchMemberGroups`object along with the URL by appending a @PathParam annotation on the service method. Could someone tell me how do I pass this object to the service without changing the type of the service to POST or PUT.

```
function fetchGroups() {

var fetchMemberGroups = new Object();
fetchMemberGroups.sEcho = 0;

$("#displayGroupsTable").dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource":"api/groupService/groups", 
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) { 
        fetchMemberGroups.iDisplayStart=oSettings._iDisplayStart;
        fetchMemberGroups.iDisplayLength=oSettings._iDisplayLength;
        fetchMemberGroups.sEcho=fetchMemberGroups.sEcho+1;
        oSettings.jqXHR=$.ajax( { 
            "contentType" : 'application/json',
             "dataType": 'json',
             "type": "GET",
             "url": sSource, 
             "data": JSON.stringify(fetchMemberGroups),
             "success": fnCallback
        });},
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "mData": "groupName" },
                      { "mData": "numberOfMembers"},
                      { "mData": "distinguishedName"}
                  ]

});
}
```

The server side code:

```
@GET
@Path("groups")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getGroups(@Context HttpServletRequest request, PagingObject fetchGroupsObject) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

you should not be using the oTable api to set your parameters to send to the server...because oSettings doesnt exist yet, oTable hasnt been created so there's no oSettings

you should not have to specify sEcho, iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength those are automatically created in a server side implementation by the framework

what you do need to do is evaluate them in your query to get your result limit, ect

if you could i would suggest trying the following, and see if it returns anything in the network inspector of firebug/chrome tools

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                            fnCallback(json);
                        });
```

**Previous**

Im pretty sure your fnServerData is off, or at least its unlike anything ive seen

Typically i do something similar to this, where lastname is an additional parameter, and as getJSON you know its a get:

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
    aoData.push( { "name" : "LastName", "value" : "$('#LastName').val()" } );
                        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                            fnCallback(json);
                        });
```

The 500 error also sems like the url doesnt exist, have you tried opening the url on its own rather than from ajax?

Comment: Yes I am able to. The exact error I get is "No Injection source found for a parameter"

Comment: i believe your parameters are being set incorrectly, see edits